# How do I dissect a string to create a new variable?

Tags: r, string

I have a sample dataframe:

```
ID   Code
 1   1, 1, 1
 2   1, 2, 3
 3   2, 2
 4   3
 5   2, 1
```

Where "Code" consists of colors coded 1, 2, 3, or a combination of those. "Code" is of character type. I want to create a new column based on the value(s) in "Code", so that I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID   Code       Description
 1   1, 1, 1          White
 2   1, 2, 3       Multiple           
 3   2, 2             Green
 4   3                 Blue
 5   2, 1          Multiple
```

The new column is coded as "Multiple" if there is more than 1 color in "Code"

Comment: Please use `dput` to produce your example data.frame and post the result in your question. At the moment, it is not clear what the structure of your second variable is.

Answer (score 1):

We create an named `key/value` `vector`, then split the 'Code' to create the expected output based on matching the 'v1'

```
v1 <- setNames( c('White', 'Green', 'Blue'), 1:3)
df1$Description <- unname(sapply(strsplit(df1$Code, ",\\s*"), function(x) 
      if(length(unique(x))> 1) 'Multiple' else v1[unique(x)]))
df1
#    ID    Code Description
#1  1 1, 1, 1       White
#2  2 1, 2, 3    Multiple
#3  3    2, 2       Green
#4  4       3        Blue
#5  5    2, 1    Multiple
```